# HTML5 History API. Как добавить запись

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-history-api

Как сделать добавление новой записи в `Url`, не переписывая существующую?

Пример: `/index.html/[новая запись истории]`

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом `history.pushState()`:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

[Полная статья по History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API).